# Placing multivalued dependencies in their own tables but feeling confused

Tags: sql

I have a table in BCNF and I need to find the multivalued dependencies but I am not sure if I have created new tables that provide sensible information.

I have an employee table, projects table and an emp_work table. The table in BCNF in called Emp_Work and I am using the composite primary key of EmpID, ProjName, and WrkDate. The table shows employees who can work on different projects, on different days at different hours.

```
Emp_Work (EmpID, ProjName, WrkDate, WrkHrs)
```

4NF tables:

```
EmployeeProj (EmpID, ProjName)

EmplopyeeWkDates (EmpID, WrkDate)

EmployeeHrs (EmpId, WrkHrs)
```

Is this correct? Looking at the new tables, I am not seeing a true picture of the information. For example, an employee works on a specific project on multiple days at different hours but the way the tables are now created I am not seeing a true picture of the information. EmployeeHrs gives me the employees and the hours they worked but without knowing what dates the hours relate to and the projects that relate to the hours have left me confused. Did I misidentify the multivalued dependencies? I am new at this so I need some help please.

Answer (score 0):

```
Emp_Work (id, Emp_projectId, employeeId, start_date_with_hour, end_date_with_hour)
```

You don’t need to create table for hours and dates, you can store it on one table

Example visual

```
id, emp_projectId, employeeId, start_date_with_hour, end_date_with_hour
1, 1, 1, 21-04-2019 13:00, 21-04-2019 17:00
2, 1, 1, 22-04-2019 13:00, 22-04-2019 19:00 

Employee1 started to working at 21-04-2019 13:00 and finished work at 21-04-2019 17:00 for project1

Employee1 started to working at 22-04-2019 13:00 and finished work at 22-04-2019 19:00 for project1
```

Example sql codes

```
Get how many hours worked at date
Select *, datediff(hour,end_date_with_hour, start_date_with_hour) as workHour from emp_work where EmployeeId = 1 and emp_projectId = 1 

Result : 

1, 1, 1, 21-04-2019 13:00, 21-04-2019 17:00, 4
2, 1, 1, 22-04-2019 13:00, 22-04-2019 19:00, 6
```

Comment: Thank you. So, the dates worked and hours worked can stay in a table with the Employee_ID? It this is the case, will the table be in 4NF?